# Ping works , but unable to do ssh

Tags: 12.04, ssh, ping

I disabled the firewall with `sudo ufw disable`, I can ping the server, the server can ping me but I can't `ssh` to it:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/acme# ssh 192.168.1.6 ssh: connect to host
192.168.1.6 port 22: Connection refused
```

I removed ssh and reinstalled :

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

But still ssh is not working and I get the error

> connection refused

How do I tackle this issue?

Here are some other stuff I have tried so far:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/acme# sudo service ssh start
start: Job is already running: ssh

root@ubuntu:/home/acme# ps aux | grep ssh
acme      6548  0.0  0.0  12576   320 ?        Ss   04:09   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
root     22219  0.0  0.1  50040  2852 ?        Ss   05:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     22277  0.0  0.0   8116   896 pts/0    S+   05:17   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

**Update for future visitors**

removing and reinstalling ssh on the server worked for me :

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

Comment: I assume you reinstalled `ssh` on your server (192.168.1.6)? Please share it's configuration file.

Comment: Can you test SSH locally on the server? eg `ssh localhost`

Comment: This issue is solved now. perhaps by disabling firewall on both the machines. Also as suggested by Andrejs, I had to reinstall ssh on 192.168.1.6, I think I did not do this earlier. I was installing on the machine from which I was doing ssh

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs though the issue is solved , but can you tell me where do we get that configuration file?

Comment: SSH server configuration file is located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Please answer your own question and mark it as solved later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling ssh on the **server** worked for me :

My master node is : 192.168.1.6

My client is:  192.168.1.4

On the master I did this:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

Now from my client I did this:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# ssh 192.168.1.6
root@192.168.1.6's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

131 packages can be updated.
67 updates are security updates.

Last login: Thu Oct 24 15:18:34 2013 from ubuntu.local
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens in UBUNTU because, by default only openssh-client is present. 
To access ur remote Ubuntu, you'll never ssh server running in remote machine. Just install server.

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a weird shot-in-the-dark, but make sure your IP didn't change. I had this issue once - I set a `.bashrc` alias `alias sshdev='ssh me@123.2.3.4'` as my typical way of logging in, and one day I started getting the following error:

```
ME-M-216C:~ me$ sshdev 
ssh: connect to host 123.2.3.4 port 22: Connection refused
```

We just had a power outage at work which reset the IP's, so I was successfully pinging the 123.2.3.4 IP but it wasn't the correct machine. You can use `nslookup <IP>` to make sure it's the correct machine name that you're trying to `ssh` into.